# Matplotlib Pie Chart shows error with usage of slices

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib and pie chart shows error while using silces in there

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

slices = [7, 2, 2, 13, 15]

activities = ["Sleep", "Eat", "Play", "Study", "Entertainment"]

colors = ['c', 'm', 'r', 'b', 'g']

plt.pie(slices,
        labels=activities,
        colors=[colors],
        startangle=90,
        shadow=True,
        explode=(0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0),
        # autopct='What is written on every section',
        autopct='%1.1f%%'
        )

plt.legend()

plt.title("Pie Chart")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to pass `colors` instead of `[colors]` as the argument. The function expects a list, not a list of lists.

Please find the working code snippet below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


slices = [7,2,2,13,15]

activities = ["Sleep","Eat","Play","Study","Entertainment"]

colors = ['c','m','r','b','g']

plt.pie(slices,
        labels=activities,
        colors=colors,
        startangle=90,
        shadow=True,
        explode=(0,0,0,0.1,0),
        autopct='%1.1f%%'
        )



plt.legend()

plt.title("Pie Chart")

plt.show()
```

The above code snippet generates the following output:

[image]